# Is `<-` also for data.frames using call by reference sometimes?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a simple problem that I wanted to solve using `data.table`. I was surprised about the following behaviour, as I thought, asignements in base R are always copying:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(
  t = 1:10,
  x = "x",
  y = "y"
)
df$z <- df$y # I was assuming this is a full blown copy (since done in base R)
setDT(df)
df[t>=5, `:=`(z=x)]
df
```

So in the end I want to have for the column `z` copy of `x` in case `t>=5` and a copy of `y` otherwise. However, `y` is also changed, which I find surprising. What is the reason for that?

```
     t x y z
 1:  1 x y y
 2:  2 x y y
 3:  3 x y y
 4:  4 x y y
 5:  5 x x x
 6:  6 x x x
 7:  7 x x x
 8:  8 x x x
 9:  9 x x x
10: 10 x x x
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused ... you asked about that which you found surprising but choose to accept the answer that doesn't answer the question? Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I found both answers great and could not decide which one to accept and chose the other one because it proposed a good and intuitive way to prevent this from happening. But you are right, actually your answer fits better to my question...

Comment: I don't want to change which is accepted on my account, but it seemed inconsistent which suggested I misunderstood your question. Thank you for confirming that I read it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data.table has its own way of doing things; which you discovered one example of, trying to save on memory because at the point where the setdf happens the columns are pointing to a single source.
To get around this issue, you might choose to create z in the data.table part ;

heres an example with chaining

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(
  t = 1:10,
  x = "x",
  y = "y"
)

setDT(df)[, z := copy(y)][t>=5, z := x]
df
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally base R does "copy on write", which means if you change something in the vector then the vector is copied.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  t = 1:10,
  x = "x",
  y = "y"
)
df$z <- df$y
df$z[1] <- df$z[1] # THIS causes the copy-on-write
setDT(df)
df[t>=5, `:=`(z=x)]
df
#         t      x      y      z
#     <int> <char> <char> <char>
#  1:     1      x      y      y
#  2:     2      x      y      y
#  3:     3      x      y      y
#  4:     4      x      y      y
#  5:     5      x      y      x
#  6:     6      x      y      x
#  7:     7      x      y      x
#  8:     8      x      y      x
#  9:     9      x      y      x
# 10:    10      x      y      x
```